# Create new field in data frame with text based on string values in another field

Tags: python, string, dataframe, text, field

Below is my python data frame table.  The result I want is in the highlighted yellow column.

[image]

Below is the code logic I want to implement:

- If the "Award" column contains the words "Top IRA Advisor", then I want the "Industry_Recognition_Flag" field to say "Recognized as Top IRA Advisor".  Otherwise, I want it to be blank.

Below is the code I tried but didn't work:

```
df_rfholder['Industry_Recognition_Flag'] = np.where(df_rfholder['Award'].str.contains('(?:Top IRA Advisor)', regex = True), 'Recognized as Top IRA Advisor', '')
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use .str.match()...
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.match.html

Here is a working example:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'one' : pd.Series(['','2016 Top IRA Advisor','2016 Top IRA Advisor'], index=['a', 'b', 'c']), 'two' : pd.Series(['Recognized', 'Recognized', 'Recognized'], index=['a', 'b', 'c'])}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df["new"] = np.where(df['one'].str.match('.*Top IRA Advisor'), 'true', 'false')

print(df)
```

Comment: thx for response.  unfortunately, it did not work ... every row came back as 'true'

Comment: @PineNuts0 Strange because I used a standalone example and have been using .match() earlier. I relooked at your example and changing the regex code works for me too... df_rfholder['Industry_Recognition_Flag'] = np.where(df_rfholder['Award'].str.contains('.*Top IRA Advisor', regex = True), 'Recognized as Top IRA Advisor', '')

Comment: thx for the response; my issue is even when the value does not say Top IRA Advisor in "Award" field, the Industry_Recognition_Flag field still says "Recognized as Top IRA Advisor"

Answer (score 0):

As simple-minded as this?

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data = {'Award': 8*['']+['2016 Top IRA Advisor', '', '2016 Top IRA Advisor']}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> df
                   Award
0                       
1                       
2                       
3                       
4                       
5                       
6                       
7                       
8   2016 Top IRA Advisor
9                       
10  2016 Top IRA Advisor
>>> df['Desired Result']=df['Award'].apply(lambda x: 'Recognized as Top IRA Advisor' if x=='2016 Top IRA Advisor' else '')
>>> df
                   Award                 Desired Result
0                                                      
1                                                      
2                                                      
3                                                      
4                                                      
5                                                      
6                                                      
7                                                      
8   2016 Top IRA Advisor  Recognized as Top IRA Advisor
9                                                      
10  2016 Top IRA Advisor  Recognized as Top IRA Advisor
```